# Books keeps rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, data-structures

Books I am retrieving from an API keeps re-rendering when I resize my window. I think the problem might be related on how I handle those requests. This is the home component where I am getting books based on different categories:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import CardGroup from '../components/CardGroup';
import Banner from '../components/Banner';

export default function Home() {
  const [recommendedBooks, setRecommendedBooks] = useState([]);
  const [sciFiClassicsBooks, setSciFiClassicsBooks] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:5000')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log('Data from server:', data);

        const recommendedCategory = data.allBooks.find(category => category.category === 'Recommended');
        const sciFiClassicsCategory = data.allBooks.find(category => category.category === 'SciFi Classics');

        if (recommendedCategory) {
          setRecommendedBooks(recommendedCategory.books);
        } else {
          <p>Recommended category not found</p>
        }

        if (sciFiClassicsCategory) {
          setSciFiClassicsBooks(sciFiClassicsCategory.books);
        } else {
          <p>Scifi classic category not found</p>
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error.message);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="md:mt-3 lg:mt-8">
      <Banner />
      {recommendedBooks.length > 0 && (
        <CardGroup key="Recommended" title="Recommended" books={recommendedBooks} />
      )}
      {sciFiClassicsBooks.length > 0 && (
        <CardGroup key="SciFi Classics" title="SciFi Classics" books={sciFiClassicsBooks} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

And this is my data structure built with express.js

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(cors());

app.use('/data', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'client', 'src', 'data')));

const allBooks = [
  {
    category: 'HomeBooks',
    books: [
      { id: 1, title: 'War Bodies', author: 'Neal Asher', image: '/data/bodies.jpg', bookImg: '/data/bodies.png', authorDesc: 'The majority of Asher work is set in one future history, the "Polity" universe. It encompasses many classic science fiction tropes including world-ruling artificial intelligences, androids, hive minds and aliens. His novels are characterized by fast-paced action and violent encounters.', description: 'Long ago, the Cyberat left Earth to co-evolve with machines. Now, led by the powerful dictator Castron, their Old Guard believe that machines should replace the physical body. But these beliefs are upended with the arrival of the human Polity – and their presence ignites rebellion.', rating: 4.2, read: 31.4, bgColor: '#C1B1CF', pages: 576, price: 18 },
{Others id..... until 25}
    ]
  },
  {
    category: 'Recommended',
    books: [
      { id: 1, title: 'War Bodies', author: 'Neal Asher', image: '/data/bodies.jpg', rating: 4.5, read: 31.4, bgColor: '#C1B1CF' },
      { id: 2, title: 'Exhalation', author: 'Ted Chiang', image: '/data/exhalation.jpg', rating: 4.1, read: 21.4 },
      { id: 3, title: 'Jack Four', author: 'Neal Asher', image: '/data/jack.jpg', rating: 3.5, read: 11.4 },
      { id: 4, title: 'Children of Memory', author: 'Adrian Tchaichowsky', image: '/data/memory.jpg', rating: 4.5, read: 41.4 },
      { id: 5, title: 'The War of the Worlds', author: 'H. G. Wells', image: '/data/world.jpg', rating: 3.5, read: 11.4 },
      { id: 6, title: 'The Body Scout', author: 'Lincoln Michel', image: '/data/scout.jpg', rating: 3.5, read: 21.4 },
      { id: 7, title: 'Weaponized', author: 'Neal Asher', image: '/data/weaponized.jpg', rating: 5.5, read: 61.4 },
      { id: 8, title: 'Children of Ruin', author: 'Adrian Tchaichowsky', image: '/data/ruin.jpg', rating: 4.6, read: 35.4 },
    ]
  },
  {
    category: 'SciFi Classics',
    books: [
      { id: 9, title: 'A Desolation called Peace', author: 'Arkady Martine', image: '/data/peace.jpg', rating: 4.2, read: 31.4 },
      { id: 10, title: 'Hyperion', author: 'Dan Simmons', image: '/data/hyperion.jpg', rating: 4.4, read: 51.4 },
      { id: 11, title: 'Red Mars', author: 'Kim Robinson', image: '/data/mars.jpg', rating: 3.5, read: 31.4 },
      { id: 12, title: 'Children of Time', author: 'Adrian Tchaichowsky', image: '/data/time.jpg', rating: 4.5, read: 51.4 },
      { id: 13, title: 'Foundation', author: 'Isaac Asimov', image: '/data/foundation.jpg', rating: 4.9, read: 61.4 },
      { id: 14, title: '2001: A Space Odissey', author: 'Arthur Clarke', image: '/data/odissey.jpg', rating: 4.5, read: 51.4 },
      { id: 15, title: 'Dune', author: 'Frank Herbert', image: '/data/dune.jpg', rating: 5.5, read: 61.4 },
      { id: 16, title: 'Contact', author: 'Carl Sagan', image: '/data/contact.jpg', rating: 4.6, read: 45.4 },
    ]
  },
  {
    category: 'Cyberpunk',
    books: [
      { id: 17, title: 'Altered Carbon', author: 'Richard Moorgan', image: '/data/carbon.jpg', rating: 4.2, read: 31.4 },
      { id: 18, title: 'Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?', author: 'Philip K. Dick', image: '/data/android.jpg', rating: 4.4, read: 51.4 },
      { id: 11, title: 'Red Mars', author: 'Kim Robinson', image: '/data/mars.jpg', rating: 3.5, read: 31.4 },
      { id: 12, title: 'Children of Time', author: 'Adrian Tchaichowsky', image: '/data/time.jpg', rating: 4.5, read: 51.4 },
      { id: 13, title: 'Foundation', author: 'Isaac Asimov', image: '/data/foundation.jpg', rating: 4.9, read: 61.4 },
      { id: 19, title: 'Snow Crash', author: 'Neal Stephenson', image: '/data/crash.jpg', rating: 4.5, read: 51.4 },
      { id: 20, title: 'Neuromancer', author: 'William Gibson', image: '/data/neuro.jpg', rating: 5.5, read: 61.4 },
      { id: 16, title: 'Contact', author: 'Carl Sagan', image: '/data/contact.jpg', rating: 4.6, read: 45.4 },
    ]
  },
  {
    category: 'Hardscifi',
    books: [
      { id: 10, title: 'Hyperion', author: 'Dan Simmons', image: '/data/hyperion.jpg', rating: 4.4, read: 51.4 },
      { id: 9, title: 'A Desolation called Peace', author: 'Arkady Martine', image: '/data/peace.jpg', rating: 4.2, read: 31.4 },
      { id: 12, title: 'Children of Time', author: 'Adrian Tchaichowsky', image: '/data/time.jpg', rating: 4.5, read: 51.4 },
      { id: 11, title: 'Red Mars', author: 'Kim Robinson', image: '/data/mars.jpg', rating: 3.5, read: 31.4 },
      { id: 13, title: 'Foundation', author: 'Isaac Asimov', image: '/data/foundation.jpg', rating: 4.9, read: 61.4 },
      { id: 16, title: 'Contact', author: 'Carl Sagan', image: '/data/contact.jpg', rating: 4.6, read: 45.4 },
      { id: 14, title: '2001: A Space Odissey', author: 'Arthur Clarke', image: '/data/odissey.jpg', rating: 4.5, read: 51.4 },
      { id: 15, title: 'Dune', author: 'Frank Herbert', image: '/data/dune.jpg', rating: 5.5, read: 61.4 },
    ]
  },
  {
    category: 'AndroidsRobots',
    books: [
      { id: 23, title: 'I Robot', author: 'Isaac Asimov', image: '/data/irobot.jpg', rating: 4.2, read: 31.4 },
      { id: 18, title: 'Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?', author: 'Philip K. Dick', image: '/data/android.jpg', rating: 4.4, read: 51.4 },
      { id: 21, title: 'Ready Player One', author: 'Ernest Cline', image: '/data/ready.jpg', rating: 3.5, read: 31.4 },
      { id: 22, title: 'The Echo Wife', author: 'Sarah Gailey', image: '/data/echo.jpg', rating: 4.5, read: 51.4 },
      { id: 13, title: 'Foundation', author: 'Isaac Asimov', image: '/data/foundation.jpg', rating: 4.9, read: 61.4 },
      { id: 14, title: '2001: A Space Odissey', author: 'Arthur Clarke', image: '/data/odissey.jpg', rating: 4.5, read: 51.4 },
      { id: 15, title: 'Dune', author: 'Frank Herbert', image: '/data/dune.jpg', rating: 5.5, read: 61.4 },
      { id: 16, title: 'Contact', author: 'Carl Sagan', image: '/data/contact.jpg', rating: 4.6, read: 45.4 },
    ]
  },
  {
    category: 'Spaceopera',
    books: [
      { id: 15, title: 'Dune', author: 'Frank Herbert', image: '/data/dune.jpg', rating: 5.5, read: 61.4 },
      { id: 9, title: 'A Desolation called Peace', author: 'Arkady Martine', image: '/data/peace.jpg', rating: 4.2, read: 31.4 },
      { id: 10, title: 'Hyperion', author: 'Dan Simmons', image: '/data/hyperion.jpg', rating: 4.4, read: 51.4 },
      { id: 11, title: 'Red Mars', author: 'Kim Robinson', image: '/data/mars.jpg', rating: 3.5, read: 31.4 },
      { id: 12, title: 'Children of Time', author: 'Adrian Tchaichowsky', image: '/data/time.jpg', rating: 4.5, read: 51.4 },
      { id: 13, title: 'Foundation', author: 'Isaac Asimov', image: '/data/foundation.jpg', rating: 4.9, read: 61.4 },
      { id: 14, title: '2001: A Space Odissey', author: 'Arthur Clarke', image: '/data/odissey.jpg', rating: 4.5, read: 51.4 },
      { id: 16, title: 'Contact', author: 'Carl Sagan', image: '/data/contact.jpg', rating: 4.6, read: 45.4 },
    ]
  },
];

app.get('/', (_, res) => {
  res.json({ allBooks });
});

app.get('/book/:id', (req, res) => {
  const bookId = parseInt(req.params.id);
  console.log('Requested Book ID:', bookId); // Move this line here
  const book = findBookById(bookId);

  if (book) {
    res.json({ book });
  } else {
    res.status(404).json({ error: 'Book not found' });
  }
});

function findBookById(id) {
  for (const category of allBooks) {
    for (const book of category.books) {
      if (book.id === id) {
        return book;
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
}

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

I don't know if the problem is related to how I implemented the server code. This is my first full stack project. Of course I fetched those data succesfully but I think I am looping them as well at the same time.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what "the problem" actually is? Re-rendering in and of itself is not a problem. Is it re-fetching? Are you observing poor performance in the form of UI lag or something else?

Comment: Yes it is. Screen flickers when I resize and when I add different books based on different ids in the cart component

Comment: In the console I see this: Requested Book ID: 3
Requested Book ID: 3
Requested Book ID: 3
Requested Book ID: 3
Requested Book ID: 3
Requested Book ID: 3
Requested Book ID: 3
Requested Book ID: 3
Requested Book ID: 3
Requested Book ID: 3
Requested Book ID: 3
Requested Book ID: 3
Requested Book ID: 3
Requested Book ID: 3
Requested Book ID: 3
Requested Book ID: 3
Requested Book ID: 3
Requested Book ID: 3

Comment: That log isn't even in the same API endpoint that your React code uses?

Comment: The log is in the vs code terminal, it shows when I click on a specific book